Did Aristotle believe that the soul influences the body?
In De Anima, Aristotle states that the soul of an animal is realized in its physical form.
Does this mean that he believes souls are like biological blueprints, and that when applied to any sort of matter, that matter would coalesce into the form associated with that soul?
Or does it just mean that the soul of a person enables specific potentialities? And if it’s that loose of a scenario, why aren’t there more diverse applications of potentiality (e.g. why is the ability to taste always relegated to the same spot on the body if the only thing specifically granted by the soul was “ability to taste”)?

You need to be careful not to import your own idea of what a soul is into Aristotle's writing.

See Aristotle’s Psychology: the soul “is a first actuality of a natural body which has life in potentiality” (De Anima, ii 1, 412a27–8), all claims which apply to plants, animals and humans alike. And see details in Psychic Faculties
